# Azure DevOps pipelines: Cancel multiple pending jobs in queue

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps pipelines, How do I cancel all pending jobs for a job pool. I've got lots queued and couldn't see where I can cancel all the jobs I have waiting.

Answer (score 6):

Azure devops doesnot yet have this feature to cancel all the pending jobs in batch from the UI partal.

You can write scripts to call rest api to cancel all the pending jobs as walkaround. Check out below steps:

First, use [list build rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get all the pending jobs.

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?statusFilter=notStarted&api-version=5.1`

Then, use [update build api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to cancel the pending jobs:

`PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.1`

See below powershell scripts for reference:

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get a **Personal access token** that will be used in below scripts.

```
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?statusFilter=notStarted&api-version=5.1"

$pat="Personal Access Token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$pendingJobs=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url-Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method get -ContentType "application/json" 

$jobsToCancel = $pendingJobs.value

#Pending jobs donot consume the job agents in the agent pool. To filter the definition name to cancel pending jobs for a particular pipeline, you can use below filter criteria. 
#$jobsToCancel = $pendingJobs.value | where {$_.definition.Name -eq "{Name of your pipeline }"}

#call update api to cancel each job.
ForEach($build in $jobsToCancel)
{
   $build.status = "Cancelling"
   $body = $build | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
   $urlToCancel = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$($build.id)?api-version=5.1"
   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlToCancel -Method Patch -ContentType application/json -Body $body -Header @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}
```

You can also [submit a new feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click **Suggest a feature** and choose **azure devops**) to Microsoft development team for supporting cancelling pending jobs in batch.  Hopefully they will consider adding this feature in the future sprint.

Comment: I've used your script for the exact same problem, but I'm getting an exception in the `Invoke-RestMethod``VERBOSE: PATCH <server-url>_apis/build/builds/12495&api-version=5.0 with -1-byte payload` - I've checked the `$body` is fully populated and in json format.

Comment: Add `&definitions=<ur-build-definitionid>` to narrow down the cancellation to one build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I find that using v6 of the api works, but instead of PATCH use DELETE.

(Reusing some of the code from @Levi Lu-MSFT)

```
$url= "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?statusFilter=notStarted&api-version=6.0-preview"

$pendingJobs=Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $url -ContentType "application/json" 

$jobsToCancel = $pendingJobs.value

#$jobsToCancel = $pendingJobs.value | Where {$_.definition.Name -eq "{Name of your pipeline }"}

ForEach($build in $jobsToCancel)
{
   $urlToCancel = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$($build.id)?api-version=6.0-preview"
   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlToCancel -Method DELETE -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Body $body
}
```